# Efficient way to handle more items in android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have large number of items in a database, its having images and content, I need to display it in android listview as (image, content),

what is the Efficient way to query database and display these large set of data in a android listview.?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to fundamentally look at the best way to show the data; if you have such a large amount of data that it is difficult to store in a list view, won't a different way of accessing the data, through something such as a search function work better?

However, if you want to use a ListView, I would obviously refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html , but I would make sure that you have a good reason to do it this way, unless I am understanding your question wrong, as I feel that it might not be the most efficient or nice way to show data.

Also, what type of database are you using, an online database or a locally stored one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different types of adapters. For database is most appropriate to use [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html). where you tell which cursor to use. You can also manually walk through elements in DB and save them in some other object in array and then you can have array Addapter in which you pass your array of object. In each case you must set binder or override method onCreateView where you tell which parameter go in which filed.

Check : http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Ref : [show data from database to listView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368375/show-data-from-database-to-listview-android)